# Finding if points are contained between two curves

Tags: python, path, polygon, contains, fill

I came accross a bit of a problem and couldn't find a satisfying answer anywhere.

I'm looking to find the points contained between two curves, with the fact that both curves are kind of parametric, and don't have the same number of x-elements.

The matplotlib function `fill` works perfectly to fill with polygons the area between the curves. I've stumbled upon the `contains_point` function from `matplotlib_path`, but I can't find a way to get the properties of the `matplotlib.patches.Polygon` output from `fill` to use it.

Is there a way to use this, or should I take another approach possible, by doing directly what the `fill` function does to obtain the polygon (but how) ?

Plot illustating the problem:
[image: Plot illustating the problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, I managed to resolve my problem.
Using `shapely` and `descartes` (a simple pip install do the trick),

```
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon
from shapely.geometry import Point
from descartes import PolygonPatch
```

you can create the needed polygon with `Polygon` function by feeding it a tuple filed with x and y of both curves appended. You can create the polygon patch with the `PolygonPatch` function from shapely and plot it using:

```
ax.add_patch(name_of_your_patch)
```

To check if a point is included inside the polygon, you can create a `Point` object with shapely and the function:

```
name_of_your_polygon.contains(point)
```

will return a boolean.

Here is an example script (remember to import `shapely` and `descartes`):

```
main=rand(4,2)
main=tuple(map(tuple,main))    #Transform into tuple
poly=Polygon(main)             #Create filling Polygon
poly_patch=PolygonPatch(poly)  #Create Polygon Patch

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.add_patch(poly_patch)       #Draws the patch
point=Point(0.5,0.5)
print(poly.contains(point))
ax.scatter(0.5,0.5,s=10000,color='gold',marker='+')
```

In the case I plotted below, the `poly.contains(point)` function returns `True`.

[Example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWpa1.jpg)